# How do I retrieve data from Oracle from multiple tables and columns without duplicates?

Tags: oracle

I am trying to retrieve distinct data from 3 different tables.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT T.Topic,T.EventNo, T.EventType, T.EventLoc, T.EventDate, T.StartTime, T.EndTime, T.Details, ((ES.SFirstName || ' ' || ES.SLastName))AS SPEAKER
FROM TIMETABLE T
      , EXTERNALSPEAKER ES
      , SPEAKEREVENT SE
WHERE T.EventNo = SE.EventNo 
AND ES.SpeakerID = SE.SpeakerID 
AND EventDate >= SYSDATE
ORDER BY EventDate;
```

The result looks like this:

```
Normalization by Evaluation for Sized Dependent Types   4   Lecture CH.03.024, FLOOR 1
Normalization by Evaluation for Sized Dependent Types   4   Lecture CH.03.024, FLOOR 1
Careers and Employment Information Workshop 1   Workshop    Park Plaza Westminster Bridge Hotel
Object-Oriented Software Design 2   Lecture CH.02.054, FLOOR 3
Doing for our robots what evolution did for us  3   Lecture CH.01.044, FLOOR 4
Doing for our robots what evolution did for us  3   Lecture CH.01.044, FLOOR 4
```

I have spent hours and I just can't figure it out. I am new to SQL.

Thank you!

Comment: You are probably missing a join condition somewhere.  Also I would recommend using the more standardized join syntax (https://www.dofactory.com/sql/join) it makes it easier to see what columns are missing

Comment: Thank you, it comes up with the same result :(:(

Comment: It's difficult to align the posted output with the projection of the posted query. Do they come from the same source? Either way, this is going to come down to the **data**. If you want us to help you need to provide sample input records which reproduce the problem you complain of.

Answer (score 0):

We've got too few information to suggest something *smart*, so here's the most obvious "solution":  **DISTINCT**.

```
select DISTINCT T.Topic, ...
```